# How to create a real-time HTML editor?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a PHP website where when you put a text in a `textarea`, and the content of the input will be put in a table in real time to have a preview of the result.

Is there a way to make this possible? I don't have any idea how to do this. I've found a lot of sites on the internet like "Real Time HTML Editor", "Instant HTML" and they do exactly what I want. Is there any JavaScript that could make this possible?

Comment: please read SO guidelines before posting new queries ..

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="real"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txt').keyup(function(){
        $('#real').html($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you want this to behave like Real Time HTML Editor (i.e. typing "<b>this is bold</>" results in the display text being formatted as bold text), then it should be `$('#real').html($(this).val());`

Comment: You'd probably want to use `.html()` if the source string is HTML itself.

Comment: When you put this code inside repl.it and it works....